# Questions with ignored tags don't show up on Stack Overflow when I use a desktop browser and show up when I use a mobile phone browser

Tags: support, tags, ignored-tags

I ignore particular tags to fine grain the question list, and I have enabled *Hide questions in your ignored tags*, so the corresponding questions (with tags I ignore) **don't show up** when I use the browser on my desktop PC; however, this setting doesn't propagate when I use the Stack Overflow website from the mobile phone browser. I use Google Chrome in both cases.

(Note: I'm using the mobile **browser**, not the no-longer-maintained mobile app.)

Why does this happen so?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219791/discussion-on-question-by-giorgi-tsiklauri-questions-with-ignored-tags-dont-sho).

Comment: I cannot find the setting "Hide questions in your ignored tags", either from a mobile browser or a desktop browser, so I cannot reproduce this. From searching google it seems there used to be such a setting, maybe it was removed?

Comment: @HugoRune see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/321052/703032).